# What does this game use as it's "engine"

Tags: flash

http://chrome.angrybirds.com

On what is this game based on? Does somebody know?
HTML5? Flash? JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is built on WebGL which essentially extends the JavaScript Library and uses the canvas element in HTML5.